# Db2 .SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505

Tags: java, scala, db2

I am reading from a table in Oracle and inserting the entire dump into Db2.
The table structures are the same.I am using Simple scala class which does the above mentioned task. I have set the insert batchsize as 300. After a few batches gets updated, the class is throwing the below exception

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Error for batch element #10: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=1;PME.TM_ASSET_LQA_DETL, DRIVER=4.13.127
   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:673) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:60) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:127) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:481) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:70) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:57) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.tb.a(tb.java:225) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.a(oo.java:3434) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.d(oo.java:5550) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.a(oo.java:4992) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.c(oo.java:4664) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.executeBatch(oo.java:2934) ~[db2jcc-4.13.127.jar:na]
    at com.baml.regw.db.replicator.ReplicationRunnable$$anonfun$run$3.apply(SimpleReplicator.scala:105) ~[regw-db-replicator-0.0.933-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.baml.regw.db.replicator.ReplicationRunnable$$anonfun$run$3.apply(SimpleReplicator.scala:80) ~[regw-db-replicator-0.0.933-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
```

Since the exception was related to IntegrityConstraint I tried checking for presence of Composite primary key(ID+TimeStamp+9999-12-31 00.00.000000) but the combo is neither present in the Oracle table nor the Db2 table.
The constraints on thE Db2 table are

```
 COLUMN NAME                         UNIQUE RULE
    +ID+BUSINESS_STOP+BUSINESS_START    Primary
    +ID                                 Duplicate
    +BUSINESS_START                     Duplicate
    +LOW_QUALITY_IND                    Duplicate
    +IDENTIFIER1                        Duplicate    
    +IDENTIFIER2                        Duplicate
```

I scoured through the other such issues in SO but none of the fixes worked for me.
The code which is performing this task

```
    logger.info("Retrieving based on query string: " + queryStr + " for thread " + threadNum)
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryStr)
    val rsMd = rs.getMetaData()
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    logger.info("Query execution time: " + (end - start) + "ms.")

    done = true
    var stmtCount = 0
    Iterator.continually(rs).takeWhile(_.next()).foreach { rs =>
      if (sourceConf.hasPath("blockSize")) {
        done = false
      }

      //Subtract one to ignore the timestamp field that we are using
      for (idx <- 1 to (rsMd.getColumnCount()-extraColumnCount)) {
        try  {  
          logger.info("destStmt.setObject"+rs.getObject(idx)+" column Type "+ rsMd.getColumnType(idx))
          destStmt.setObject(idx, rs.getObject(idx), rsMd.getColumnType(idx))
        }
        catch  {
          case e:Exception => {
            logger.warn("While attempting to set (1-based) index: " + idx + 
                " to value of type " + {if(rs.getObject(idx) != null) rs.getObject(idx).getClass().getName() else "[NULL]"} + 
                " received error: " + e.getMessage())
            throw e
          }
        }
      }


      destStmt.addBatch()
      stmtCount += 1

      if(stmtCount % { if (destConf.hasPath("batchSize")) destConf.getInt("batchSize") else 200 } == 0)  {           
        destStmt.executeBatch()
        destDbConn.commit()
        destStmt.clearBatch()
        stmtCount = 0
      }
    }

    if(stmtCount > 0)  {
      destStmt.executeBatch()
      destDbConn.commit()
      destStmt.clearBatch()
    }
    rs.close()
    stmt.close()
```

Comment: @Beryllium-Thanks for your comment and guidance the issue is resolved. The source table has duplicate rows and that was the reason behind the exception.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check if there is really the same integrity constraint in your source database (Oracle). Otherwise you might import rows which exist in your source table (because there isn't a constraint), but which can't be imported in the target table.
- Check if the column indices are really the same in both tables (Oracle and DB2) *from the perspective of JDBC*. Other tools may sort by column name etc. Better yet: Use column names (iterate over the column names in the meta data). Your index-based approach won't work, if the columns are reordered which possibly happens, if columns are dropped and re-added etc. For example, if you have a `select * from x` and an `insert into x values(...)` the column order is relevant.
- Check if you have `null` values in your source table in the columns which are part of the constraint. Possibly Oracle handles `null` values in the constraint differently than DB2, if it's backed by an index.

Comment: I had already added a check for the Timestamp to be not null so as to exclude the point # 3 which you have mentioned. For Point #1 & 2 I am not sure how the indices in oracle would affect the insertion into Db2.

Comment: All I doing is a select from Oracle and insert the rows into Db2 using Preparemend Statement's batch functionality.

Comment: I have added two examples regarding #1 and #2